# Is it possible to read JSON response partially from REST api with Dart

Tags: json, api, parsing, dart, stream

Is it possible to Stream an REST API JSON response with Dart?
Ex. Response size is 5000 lines. I would like to read it line by line without first loading the whole response from the source.

I think something similar is possible with Java and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

With the `http` package, you can use the `send()` method to send the request and have a `Stream` with the response.

With `Utf8Decoder` and `LineSplitter` from `dart:convert`, you can decode and read each line as you receive it.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

main() async {
  var request = Request('GET', Uri.parse('http://localhost:8090'));
  var response = await request.send();

  var lineStream =
      response.stream.transform(Utf8Decoder()).transform(LineSplitter());

  // lineStream is a Stream<String> with each line from the response as an event.
  // We can use the listen() method or await for to read it.

  await for (String line in lineStream) {
    print(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 If I understand correctly, this won't first download the whole json response, but only incrementally?

Comment: Yes, it should fire the lines as they are downloaded and not wait for the whole file to be complete.